# angular js application structure for large applications

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I read a few articles about the directory structure for large angular js applications. So to my understanding it is a good thing to setup a modular structure. Within that modular structure you can create a feature based directory structure so that every feature has the controllers , html ,services etc all grouped together. All the 'shared' services etc I ll have in a seperate module. Where is the limit to how many controllers you can create in relation to performance/maintainibility? It is just that there a few different opninions out there how to structure this but what would be the recommended one?

Answer (score 0):

Best advice I can give you, is to clone their blank app repo. It is very well structured there and inside are many little comments about different ways of doing stuff.

[Angular seed app](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed)

All I can say is take advantage of the coding paradigms available, like, dependency injection. Using factories for singleton scope and services for everything else.

Keep it modular, keep the structure clean. After that its all up to your choice and how you best find it works.

Coding practices are more about guidelines rather then rules, but mainly what is best for you and others rather then what communities believe. It's always best to follow good coding practices out there. But really its subjective and down to you.

Do performance tests to see as well. Don't over think it.

Comment: there is no actual difference between factory and services.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is. It may be small. I've always assumed they were the same, however I remember some post saying there is a difference, in the way they are loaded. Factories are like singleton patterns. Where services are more transient, i.e. instantiated in each call (thats ninject talk, transient)

Comment: Both are single patterns... you can double check if you want. The difference you are referring to is just about the "constructor" of the class but it does not change the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great [article](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/27/13-step-guide-angularjs-modularization/) that I came across and it really mirrored how our project has grown to be structured.

We started out with using yeoman for the directory structure for the angular app - its great it sets up all the boring boilerplate stuff that is a pain.

We started out with this approach and its worked really well up until recently when I realised our directories were becoming dumping grounds.

```
    app
    |____controllers
    | |____foo.ctrl.js
    | |____bar.ctrl.js
    |____filters
    | |____baz.filter.js
    | |____hat.filter.js
    |____directives
    | |____bob.directive.js
    | |____moo.directive.js
    |____myapp.module.js
    |____services
    | |____pants.service.js
    | |____arf.service.js
    |____partials
    | |____oink.html
    | |____pat.html
```

We had about 20-30 different controllers and directives a much smaller collection of services, but never-the-less the directories no longer had any real meaning - just a dumping ground.

Our goal in the project we were working on was to develop modules that can be added as needed to projects for example a shopping cart module which should be easily *plugged* into a new project and off you go using it more or less out of the box. The only way to get this sort of a feature was to rethink our directory structure so we had some meaning again.

```
    app
    |____nonsense
    | |____nonsense.module.js
    | |____foo.ctrl.js
    | |____bar.ctrl.js
    | |____baz.filter.js
    |____apparel
    | |____apparel.module.js
    | |____hat.filter.js
    | |____pants.service.js
    |____sounds
    | |____sounds.module.js
    | |____arf.service.js
    | |____oink.html
    | |____moo.directive.js
    |____people
    | |____people.module.js
    | |____bob.directive.js
    | |____pat.html
    |____myapp.module.js
```

Now we can clearly see what a module is composed of and it gives us a greater easy in debugging modules and moving them around - it's all in one place.

There is also a best [practices](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub) google docs that talks about similar things.

In conclusion what seems to be a good structure at the start of an app may not prove to be sustainable as the app grows, but how to see something like this at the start I suppose can only come with refactoring pains and a lot of reading of best practices.

Just so there is no confusion the directory structure I have shown above came from the first link I provided - 13 Steps to AngularJS Modularization.